# How to find similatrites between two files?

Tags: text-processing

Hi i am new for linux i have two files in that one have sequence_id (file_1) and another has sequence_id with sequence (file_1). I have to do if the if the sequence_id (file_1) present in file_1 to be stored in new file.

Example:
**File_1**

```
lcl|NW_002477239.1_gene_517
lcl|NW_002477243.1_gene_364
lcl|NW_002477248.1_gene_148
lcl|NW_002477249.1_gene_419
lcl|NW_002477249.1_gene_95
```

**File_2**

```
>lcl|NW_002477253.1_gene_1
TGATGGAAGCTTCCAATTCTCCCGACCAACAATCAGTGCTCAGTGAATCTATCCTTGTTAGCGAGTCGCTTGTTCCA
>lcl|NW_002477239.1_gene_517
ATGGCTGATTTTGCAAAGGATCCTGCTCTCAACGCAGCATTATCTGCACCATGGGCGTTTCTCTGCCCTACATCAGAATTAAACGATACCATA
```

**Expected output**:

```
>lcl|NW_002477239.1_gene_517
ATGGCTGATTTTGCAAAGGATCCTGCTCTCAACGCAGCATTATCTGCACCATGGGCGTTTCTCTGCCCTACATCAGAATTAAACGATACCATA
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the format of your `File_2`? You show two very different lines (one with seq ID and sequence on the same line and another that looks like FASTA without a header). Which one is the right one?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: But what is the format? You still show two different cases: one has the id and the sequence on the same line and the other has them on separate lines. Please [edit] your question and explain what the actual format of file 2 is.

Comment: but there is no new line for between two parts. i mean id and sequence

Comment: Then please **[edit]** your question and *clarify*. Use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make your files look like code (the `{}` button). Fasta files have a `>` before each ID line. Do yours also have that? If so, why isn't it in your example?

Comment: OK, I made your sequences into actual fasta. If that is not what you have in your file, please let me know. Assuming it is indeed a regular fasta file, I am closing this as a dupe.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this bash script for getting your result with matches

```
!#/bin/bash
while read line
do
     grep $line File_2 >> file
done <./File_1
```

Comment: 1. That will just print the ID, not the sequence. 2. It will fail if any of the input lines contain spaces. 3. The loop is pointless, you could do the same thing with `grep -f File_2 File_1 > file`. 4. It will also find any IDs whose name is a substring of another (so `foo` will match `foo` and `foobar` and `barfoo` etc).

Comment: this will print whole sequence with id , grep matches string and give resulted full line.

Comment: Yes, but what if I have IDs `foo` and `foobar` and I only want `foo`? Your approach will print both `foo` which we want and `foobar` which we don't want.

Comment: ok i agree for that